# Dusk + Stripe = unable to locate element

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I open a payment form in a window and each time Dusk is struggling to find the input elements on the screen. I have tried adding `pause(3)` but that did nothing.

I am running laravel 5.5 and Dusk 2.0.

```
        $browser->waitFor('.stripe-card iframe', 30);

        // Lets make the switch to iframe
        $browser->driver
            ->switchTo()
            ->frame('__privateStripeFrame5');

        $browser->type('cardnumber', '4242424242424242')
            ->type('exp-date', '12 50')
            ->type('cvc', '123');
```

I have tried:

1. using `->pause(3000)` before `type('cardnumber')` but did nothing
2. using `->keys('input[name=cardnumber]', '4242424242424242')` but did nothing

The error that I am given
`Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textar ea[name='cardnumber']"}`

When using `keys()` i get: `Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body input[name=cardnumber]"}`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textar
ea[name='cardnumber']"}

Comment: What does the screenshot in `tests/Browser/screenshots` show?

Comment: I dont see the iframe in the screenshot

Comment: I added `->pause(3000)` - the iframe appeared and still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to everyone in a similar position to upgrade Laravel to 5.7 and Dusk to 5.0.

Dusk has a new method called `withinFrame()` which makes testing easier to write and clearer to read:

https://github.com/laravel/dusk/commit/8bfb9f01ae09d1d9ca3ce53e36b1f020c0f8dc8f

Comment: Boggles my mind why this isn't in the documentation. Every time I search for some reference to how it works it brings me back to this answer.